TBS TinyButStrong on PHP laravel : pptx template that doesn't work with certain fonts or font colors
To sum up quickly: I'm working on a mutual insurance application where the salesperson can generate a powerpoint. The powerpoint is generated thanks to a template and this template is filled with tags from the TBS TinyButStrong plugin. I have a first version where it works well. But I wanted to test something else: change the font color and font style. Then it didn't work anymore. I'd like to know if there's a list of font styles that are accepted or not.
If not, is it a TBS version problem? And is there an alternative where I can use any font or color?

Can you give more technical details on how you try to change font color and font style ?
And which property of the stye you try to modify.
The Ms Office document (pptx, docx, …) has a list of fonts used by the doc, and it is complicated to change this list.
Also, when you set a color (on a text, border, …), you can select a Theme color, or a custom color. With OpenTBS, a custom color can be replaced with any other custom color (change the color id), but a Theme color can be replaced only by another referenced Theme color (complicated). This is because the XML attributes are different.
